# Soap call in android

Tags: php, android

Please help im just new in webservice and android programming

this is my webservice

```
<br>
<?php



    function aes256_cbc_decrypt($key = '', $data = '')
    {
       $iv = $key;

      if($data == '' || $key == ''){ return ''; }

      if(32 !== strlen($key)) $key = hash('SHA256', $key, true);
      if(16 !== strlen($iv)) $iv = hash('MD5', $iv, true);
      $data = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
      $padding = ord($data[strlen($data) - 1]);
      return substr($data, 0, -$padding);
    }




        // Web Service Key
        $wskey = "Your WSKey Here"; 

        // Encryption Key;
        $key = ""; 
        $soap_result = "";
        $wsdl = "http://localhost/womb_ci/webservice/wsdl";

        try {   
        // Initialize Soap Client
        $server_wsdl = "Soap WSDL Here"; 
        $soap_server = new SoapClient($wsdl); 

        // Prepare SOAP Header Parameter Request
        // ReturnFormat : json or xml
        $header_param = array(
                'WSKey'=>$wskey,
                'ReturnFormat'=>'json'
            );

        $header_param = new SoapVar($header_param,SOAP_ENC_OBJECT);
        $soap_header = new SoapHeader($server_wsdl,'Authentication',$header_param);
        /*------------------------encryption and decreption function------------------------*/

            $Response_Result = '';

        /* ---------------- Call Soap Method (Web Service Method) -------------------- */

        // Web Service Method (Function) to Call
        $wsMethod = "WOMB_account"; 

        // Web Service Parameter
        $wsParam['WOMBaccountData'] = array( 

        'username' => 'DFDGDFG_0_40',
        'password' => '123456',

        );
        //dont know how to call this in android


        // Call Web Service Method
         echo $soap_result = $soap_server->__soapCall($wsMethod, array($wsParam), NULL,$soap_header); 


        /* -- Get Soap Response Body -- */
        // Note : SOAP Response Body contains encrypted string 


        $Response_Result = $soap_result; 

        // Decrypt $Response_Result
        $Decoded_Result = base64_decode($Response_Result);

        $Decrypted_Result = aes256_cbc_decrypt($key,$Decoded_Result);

        // Display Result
        // Note : Decrypted Result can be String or Array --> Please check the response code return type
        echo $Decrypted_Result;

        } catch(SoapException $e) {

        print_r($e);

        }


?>
```

and this is my code in android

```
    public class UserSynchronization extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String>{ 
    private Context context;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private String alertMessage;
    private String urlWebservice;

    public UserSynchronization(Context context) {
        super();
        this.context = context;

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        urlWebservice  = "http://" + WombConstants.configurationInfo.getServerIp()  + "/womb_ci/index.php/webservice/";
        Log.i("IP Address", "IP Address : " + urlWebservice);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog.setMessage("Getting Data from Local Server : Please wait....");
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.show();

//      dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
//      dialog.setProgress(0);
//      dialog.setMessage("Synchronizing Data");
//      dialog.setCancelable(false);
//      dialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(Void... users) {
        String NAMESPACE = "http://" + WombConstants.configurationInfo.getServerIp()  + "/womb_ci/webservice/wsdl";
        //String NAMESPACE = "http://womb_ci.webservice.womb_account";
        String METHODNAME = "WOMB_account";

        String SOAPACTION = "http://" + WombConstants.configurationInfo.getServerIp()  + "/womb_ci/webservice/wsdl/WOMB_account";
        SoapObject request;
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope;
        HttpTransportSE ht;
        SoapPrimitive response;
        Serializer serializer;
        String json = "";
        String wsReply;
        //String[] wsReply;
        Gson gson;

        try {
            System.out.println("NAMESPACE=" + NAMESPACE);
            System.out.println("SOAPACTION=" + SOAPACTION );
            request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHODNAME);
            //parameter
            //request.addProperty("WOMBaccountData",new HashMap<String,String>{["username","DFDGDFG_0_40"],["password","123456"]});
            request.addProperty("username","DFDGDFG_0_40");
            request.addProperty("password", "123456");
            //serialization
            envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            System.out.println("Serialize= " +  request);
            //transport
            ht = new HttpTransportSE(this.urlWebservice,5000000);
            System.out.println("Start Get Data");
            //call
            ht.call(SOAPACTION, envelope);

            wsReply = (String)envelope.getResponse();
            //byte[] decodedresponse  = new String(Base64.decode(new String(Base64.decode(wsReply, Base64.DEFAULT),Base64.DEFAULT)));
            System.out.println("WEB SERVICE RESPONSE = " + wsReply);



            //Log.d("TEST", "decodeValue = " + new String(decodedresponse));
            //String onins  = "cuenco";
            //String pare = Base64.encode(onins,Base64.DEFAULT);
            //Log.d("TEST", "encoded = " + pare);


            //gson = new Gson();
           // UserResponse r;
           // r = gson.fromJson(wsReply, UserResponse.class);
            //System.out.println("Resp r: " + r.toString());
            //UserService service = new UserService(this.context);
           // service.insert(r.getResponseValue().getUserList());
          //  System.out.println("Response : " + wsReply);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("error_UserSynchronization", e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        return "DONE ";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        dialog.dismiss();
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Synchronization " + result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

this is the response in Logcat

```
04-27 09:18:58.452 26467-26467/ph.gov.doh.womb D/InputMethodManager: windowDismissed mLockisused = false
04-27 09:18:58.452 26467-26646/ph.gov.doh.womb I/System.out: NAMESPACE=http://192.168.1.109/womb_ci/webservice/wsdl
    SOAPACTION=http://192.168.1.109/womb_ci/webservice/wsdl/WOMB_account
    Serialize= WOMB_account{username=DFDGDFG_0_40; password=123456; }
    Start Get Data
04-27 09:18:58.462 26467-26467/ph.gov.doh.womb D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled mFloatingMenuBtn : null
    *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled return false
04-27 09:18:58.482 26467-26646/ph.gov.doh.womb I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
    (HTTPLog)-Static: isShipBuild true
    (HTTPLog)-Thread-3451-671080272: SmartBonding Enabling is false, SHIP_BUILD is true, log to file is false, DBG is false
    (HTTPLog)-Thread-3451-671080272: SMARTBONDING_FEATURE_ENABLED is false
    (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
    KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
    KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
04-27 09:18:58.502 26467-26467/ph.gov.doh.womb E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
04-27 09:19:00.454 26467-26646/ph.gov.doh.womb I/System.out: WEB SERVICE RESPONSE = Array
```

the response is always the word ARRAY because i dont know how to add this in my

```
soap call $wsParam['WOMBaccountData'] = array( 

        'username' => 'DFDGDFG_0_40',
        'password' => '123456',

        );
     hope somebody can help thank you
```

Comment: http://kobjects.org/ksoap2/index.html  .. this might help you in parsing data... if you don't have any specific requirement for parsing wsdl...

Comment: sir you might know how to include this in my soap call $wsParam['WOMBaccountData'] = array( 

        'username' => 'DFDGDFG_0_40',
        'password' => '123456',

        );

Comment: please help thank you in advance